# Retrieve few attributes from different table and all attributes from a single table

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I want the same concept in hibernate ,if it
  is possible as I don't want to  write the name of each and every attribute of table.

```
   select A.*,B.column from A,B;
```

Comment: If anyone could pls answer my question

Comment: what is the relation between these two tables.

Comment: Can you please show us the entity relationship between  A and B?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use HQL for this. But you can use native SQL query in Hibernate. Then you can cast the A.* to Entity.

```
SQLQuery sq = session.createSQLQuery("select A.*,B.column from A,B");
sq.addEntity("A", Entity.class);
sq.addScalar("coulmnB", Hibernate.Long);
```

Comment: As of Hibernate 5.1.0.Final, you can perform joins between unrelated entities, see HHH-16.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define a relation between the 2 tables. 
Say for example you have 2 tables: Author and Books. Here the relation is one to one.

```
@Table(name="author")
@Entity
public class Author{

    @Id
    @Column(name="id")
    @GeneratedValue
    private long id;

    @Column(name="name")
    private String name;

    @Column(name="email")
    private String email;

    @OneToOne    
    @JoinColumn(name="book")
    private Book book;
}
```

and a Book entity will have a reference of author which will look like

```
@Table(name="book")
@Entity
public class Book{

   @Id
   @Column(name="id")
   @GeneratedValue
   private long id;

   @Column(name="title")
   private String title;

   @OneToOne
   @JoinColumn(name="author_id", referencedColumnName="id" )
   private Author author;

   @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
   @Column(name="published")
   private Date publishedDate;
}
```

now the relation is set, the author can access the data from book and vice versa. 
If you want to fetch all the contents from one entity and some from other, you will have to use Criteria, projections and transformers, which can be explained [here](http://www.java4s.com/hibernate/working-with-hibernate-projections-in-criteria/) and [here](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/search/4.4/reference/en-US/html/search-query.html#d0e6235)

Your fetch code will look like

```
Criteria oCriteria = Session.createCriteria(Book.class);
oCriteria.setProjection(Projections.projectionList().add(Projections.property("author").as("oAuthor")).add(Projections.property("title").as("title")));
oCriteria.setResultTransformer(Transformers.aliasToBean(BooksDTO.class));
List<BooksDTO> alBooks = oCriteria.list();
```

Your BooksDTO object is the bean containing your data.
BooksDTO looks like

```
public class BooksDTO{
   private Author oAuthor;

   private String title;

   .... //setters and getters
}
```

Comment: It is an `one-to-one`  association in your example.

Comment: @SandeepSukhija If the user is on Hibernate 5.1.0.Final or later, unrelated entities via HQL joins are possible.